# Best practice: should I make my webhooks.php its own page on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, webhooks, braintree

I am getting the hang of Wordpress dev and now I need to integrate Braintree webhooks. Should I go into the dashboard->pages and make a page for webhooks like that? Or is there a better thing to do for the long run??

Comment: You used the braintree plugin for wordpress for this.

Comment: @TamilSelvan I'm afraid that one day that plugin will not be updated anymore, so I'm making it myself. What do you think?